# Printing char with value over 255

Tags: char, printf

I have a problem with printf function.
It shows me 48, when i'm trying to printf char which is -720.

```
printf("%d",c)=48
```

Why is this happening ?

Comment: `char` cannot be >255. Please add code with context and variable declarations.

Comment: Can you show your declaration of your variable c and the assignment of -720?

Comment: Undefined behaviour?

Comment: Please update your question to show how you stored (or tried to store) the value `-720` in a `char`. I can almost guarantee that you *don't* have a `char` with the value `-720`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

char having the range -128 to 127. When we are assigning the value as -720. So the range overflow is occured.

When we are overflowing the value for a data type. It will enable the bits with in the range. When the range is exceed the 127 it will start the allocation from the -128. So it 
will continue until the given range is come to an end.

For example you are assigning the value value to char is `char a=255`. If you print this
using %d it will print the value as -1. It will allocate 128 characters in positive 0 to 127.
Now remaining is 127. It will allocate from the negative side. So the -128 - 127. Now the answer is -1.

Answer (score 1):

In most compilers char variables can only contain values from -128 to 127 or from 0 to 255. Your value of -720 overflowed and resulted into 48.

Comment: I understand that, but why this value is 48 ?

Comment: -720 as Int16 is 1111110100110000 in binary. Since Char is Int8 it will only use the 8 most right bit, which are 00110000, which is 48 in decimal.

Comment: @TheGuest: Strictly speaking, converting an `int` value of `-720` to `char` (assuming plain `char` is signed) yields an implementation-defined result (or raises an implementation-defined signal, but I've never seen that). In practice, it almost always grabs just the low-order 8 bits.